# How to change drawable in an ImageView based on radioButton selection in my android app

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

I am looking for a way to change the drawable image source based on radio button selection.

Imageview displays image 1
radio button 1 selected

if radio button 2 selected
imageview displays image 2

etc...

any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Thank you
this is what i have in the java file:

```
    private OnClickListener rollRightlistener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            roll_left.setChecked(false);
            roll_right.setChecked(true);
            ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rol_off_45_mainimage);
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.cube_rolling_45_right);
        }
    };
```

getting multiple markers at this line error where you see ImageView i = and also ImageView cannot be resolved to a type.

any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen for the change and the set the background draw-able:

```
private OnClickListener radio_listener1 = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.View);
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

    }
};

private OnClickListener radio_listener2 = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.View);
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
    }
};
```

---

```
final RadioButton radio_red = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_red);
final RadioButton radio_blue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_blue);
radio_red.setOnClickListener(radio_listener1);
radio_blue.setOnClickListener(radio_listener2);
```

---

```
      <RadioGroup
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_red"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Red" />
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Blue" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: just curious to get a little more in depth. what if i had 2 radio that decide imageView. If Radio 1, radio 3 set imageview or if radio 1, radio 2 set imageview... if there a way to set an onclicklistener for multiple radio to determine drawable.

Comment: Can you re word that please? 

I'm not sure what your getting at but basically you can set a click listener for each radio button, in a radio group only one radio button can be active at a time, so you press one and the other one turns off

Comment: in this case that i am working on.. i have 3 radio groups. based on the combination of one radio from each group will determine imageview src. radio group 1 has radio a, b, c. radio group 2 has d, e and radio group 3 has f, g, h. so if radio a, d, f, display image 1, if radio a, d, g display image 2... and so on

Comment: Hmm, so you want a combination of different radio groups to select an image, I believe what you need to do is make some serious logic. maybe you can use Boolean values to find out which one is on, so lets say one radio button it pressed, you set the Boolean representing that radio button is true and all the Boolean values representing the other radio buttons in that group as false, and then have a method which sorts out which values are true and which ones are false and set a image view according to the result

Answer (score 0):

this site has been extremely useful to me, so it feels great to be giving back.

RE: Kevin M (Feb 11, 2012) - "...what if I had x (x > 1) radio buttons that decide image view"

This works:
If you had them in a radio group, then only one will be selected at any given time. So your task is to find which one.

EDIT: code edited to address the three radio group scenario in your follow-up comment

```
public void imgchnggrps(View v)
{
    RadioButton two = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.two);
    RadioButton three = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.three);
    RadioButton first = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.first);

    grp1index = 0;
    if (two.isChecked()) {
        grp1index = 1
    } else if (three.isChecked()) {
    grp1index = 2;
    } else if (first.isChecked()) {
    grp1index = 3;
    } else { //you don't need this else, but for completion
        grp1index = 0;
    }

    grp2index = 0;
    if (two.isChecked()) {
        [...]
    }

    grp3index = 0;
    if (two.isChecked()) {
        [...]
    }

    imgchng(grp1index, grp2index, grp3index);
}

 public void imgchng(a, b, c)
    String img = default_image; //this is a string form of the drawable
    switch a{
         case 0:
              switch b{
                    case 0:
                          switch c{
                                case 0: img = "thisimage" // drawable resource's id

                          }
                     break;
         }
         break;
         case 1:
              (switch b and c as above)
         break; 
         case 2:
              (switch as above)
         break;    
         }

    int viewid = getResources().getIdentifier(yourimageviewid, "id", yourpackagename);
    int imgid = getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable", yourpackagename);
    ImageView thisview = (ImageView) findViewById(viewid);
    thisview.setImageResource(imgid);
}
```

Then, in your layout file, assign this method to the onclick event for each radio button, like this:
android:onClick = "imgchnggrps"

Hope this helps.